# Java Socket not sending after flush

Tags: java, ios, sockets, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to send a message (using `Protobuf`) to a `socket server` that lives on an `iOS` device.  I can only get the message to send once the socket is closed.

I believe this is because the `buffer` is only getting truly flushed on the socket close.
I think I've done everything to ensure that this isn't the case.  However, I must be missing something.

Here's my code.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("::1", 1337);

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

//this is my generated protobuf class
Wire.Envelope message = Wire.Envelope.newBuilder().setType(Wire.MessageType.GET_DEVICE_DETAILS).setId(69).setMessage(Wire.GetDeviceDetailsRequest.newBuilder().build().toByteString()).build();

socket.setSendBufferSize(message.getSerializedSize());
System.out.println("Send buffer size: " + socket.getSendBufferSize());
message.writeDelimitedTo(out);
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
out.flush();
```

Comment: You can answer these questions yourself using a tool like wireshark, or netcat, or even another little Java program to receive the message.